# Why and how images are kept in one image?

Tags: html, image

I've noticed that recently sites began to keep images in one big image.
For example google.com

[image: google]

We see a lot of little images on left side. But really is one image:

[image]

How these images are cut and shown? (firebug says that it's just  element with width and height, but where X and Y position is pointed and how?)

Thanks for reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with css background the image is moved to the right position. the other part of the image is not shown, because the element with the image as background is exactly as big as the wanted picture part.

try changing the px values in the css in the background part. you should see the image moving

```
<span style="background-position:-20px -132px" class="micon"></span>
```

here you see the background-position which is used for this image

Comment: how to do it with non-img element with background-image - i understand.
But there is <img> element (without background-image)

Comment: i can't find a <img> element. what do you mean? give me some markup

Comment: here it is: http://img-url.com/u/1-1301412105.png  (screenshot of google source in firebug)

Comment: look at the css of this tag `#logo img {
    border: 0 none;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -41px;
}`

Comment: yes, I see... I'll read some articles - think - I'll understand better. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This technology is called [CSS Sprite](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/). To reduce the http connections number needed to load multiple images. Usually this is done by designer.

Answer (score 3):

This is called "**CSS Sprites**".

There are a lot of informations on Internet about that. In random order :

- [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/)
- [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/)
- [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites)

And many more ...